# FusionCharts: cannot style parts of the chart

Tags: javascript, json, styles, fusioncharts

I am using JSON format to style a FusionChart. When I change the properties of the chart as whole, the changes show up on the chart. However, when I change the individual elements (using the format found [here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/index.html?Introduction/JSChartingCapabilities.html), under the heading "Using Styles to specify font properties for individual titles") the changes do not show up on my chart.

Here is my code:

```
dataSource: {
            //works    
            chart: {
                    paletteColors: PALETTE_COLORS,
                    showBorder: "0",
                    formatNumber: "1",
                    formatNumberScale: "0",
                    numberPrefix: '$',
                    labelSepChar: ': ',
                    toolTipSepChar: ': ',
                    bgColor: 'FFFFFF',
                    seriesNameInToolTip: "0",
                    decimals: options.unit() === 'ppd' ? 2 : 0,

                    showLegend: options.showBudget() ? "1" : "0"
                },
                //doesn't work
                styles: {
                    definition: [{
                        name: "myDataValuesFont",
                        type: "font",
                        size: "24"
                    }]
                },
                application: [{
                    toobject: "tooltip",
                    styles: "myDataValuesFont"
                }]
            }
```

What am I doing wrong?